# Can I roll back files synced with dropbox

Tags: dropbox

One of my computer got infected by encryption virus. Most files are encrypted.

Only one computer got hit.

However, dropbox sync those files with all the files

In badgers, you added 4269 files. 3/2/2015 4:02 PM
 In badgers, you edited 10063 files. 3/2/2015 4:02 PM

How do I revert back to that file?

Answer (score 1):

Turn off or disconnect from network the infected PC and from another one login to the web interface in https://www.dropbox.com.

From there, you can use right-click to rollback to an specific date.

If you want to do it for a full directory you have to use external tools like this https://github.com/clark800/dropbox-restore